Different Combinatorics Approaches don't yield the same result
I’m using two different approaches to solve the same problem and I don’t understand why I don’t get the same result. I want to assign three numbers to random buckets numbered 1 to 10.
Approach 1: Assigning numbers directly to buckets

I have 3 numbers and 10 buckets.
Each number has 10 choices of buckets.
Total number of combinations: 10 * 10 * 10 = 10^3 = 1000

Approach 2: Using borders between buckets

I have 3 numbers and 9 borders between the 10 buckets.
I'm arranging these 12 elements (3 numbers + 9 borders) in a line.
Total number of arrangements: 12! (12 factorial)
However,
The order of the borders doesn't matter. There are 9! ways to arrange the 9 borders.
The order of the numbers instead does matter.
So, I divide 12! by 9! to account for the indistinguishable borders.
Final answer: 12! / 9! = 1320

Why the difference?

The first one is correct, the second approach counts some cases multiple times. More precisely: Approach 2 counts the number of ways to distribute the numbers to ten ordered lists.
For example, take the case where numbers $2$ and $3$ go to the third bucket and number $1$ goes to the seventh bucket. Approach 2 counts this both as $||23||||1|||$ and as $||32||||1|||$, where $|$ denotes the nine indistinguishable borders between buckets. It is even worse if all three numbers go to the same bucket, as there are six ways to choose the order of the three numbers within the bucket. You are counting cases with all numbers in the same bucket a whooping six times!
There are $270$ cases of two number being in the same bucket ($10$ for choosing the double bucket times $9$ for choosing the single bucket times $3$ for choosing the number that is alone). As they are counted twice instead of once, this accounts for a difference of $270$. The remaining difference of $50$ stems from the all-in-one-bucket cases. There are ten of them and each is counted six times instead of once.

@trueblueanil It says "buckets numbered $1$ to $10$ in the first paragraph.

For putting distinct objects into distinct buckets uniformly at random,  your first approach is correct
In your second approach, you have created a  hodgepodge.
For a case of identical numbers into distinct buckets, the formula (using stars and bars) would give $\binom{3+10-1}{10-1} = 220$
So using $220$ and then multiplying it by $3!$ gives a result that is neither here nor there ! (Neither placing distinct numbers into distinct buckets, nor placing identical numbers into distinct buckets)
$\underline{\mathtt{Added}}$
You can first take the buckets to be identical, and then tediously  convert it to distinct numbers in distinct buckets as under, for the three possible patterns:
$3000000000: \binom{10}1=10$
$2100000000: \binom{10}1\binom91\cdot\frac{3!}{2!} = 270$
$1110000000: \binom{10}3\cdot3! =720 \;\;total\;\boxed{1000}$
But what would be the point ?

Where does probability enter? The question is purely about combinatorics, not about probability.

I have deleted reference to probability
